# Disable JOOQ warnings

Tags: jooq

Is there a way to disable warnings made by JOOQ's codegen? It creates lots of logs that I'd like to omit.

```
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3070, 13): 'Subltree' is deprecated.
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3082, 1): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.Deprecated' instead
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3088, 13): 'Subltree' is deprecated.
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3099, 1): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.Deprecated' instead
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3105, 13): 'Subltree' is deprecated.
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3210, 1): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.Deprecated' instead
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3215, 13): 'Text2ltree' is deprecated.
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3225, 1): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.Deprecated' instead
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3229, 13): 'Text2ltree' is deprecated.
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3238, 1): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.Deprecated' instead
w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3242, 13): 'Text2ltree' is deprecated.
w: [...]/LocationsDao.kt: (137, 5): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.Deprecated' instead
w: [...]/LocationsDao.kt: (143, 5): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.Deprecated' instead
w: [...]/LocationsRecord.kt: (64, 25): No cast needed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message:

> w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3070, 13): 'Subltree' is deprecated.

Can be turned off by specifying the `<deprecated/>` flag:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <generate>

      <!-- Turn off all deprecation notices -->
      <deprecated>false</deprecated>

      <!-- Turn off deprecation notices on unknown types -->
      <deprecationOnUnknownTypes>false</deprecationOnUnknownTypes>
    </generate>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

Of course, the underlying problem (the fact that jOOQ doesn't know how to bind this data type), won't go away, so you might as well just exclude the routine from being generated with the appropriate `<excludes/>` expression.

The other message:

> w: [...]/Routines.kt: (3082, 1): This annotation is deprecated in Kotlin. Use '@kotlin.Deprecated' instead

Is a bug: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11057. But it will also be removed if you specify the above flag.

Comment: Great to know. Thanks!